# Magento sale watermark

Tags: magento

Due to being a new to Magento world, I have limited understating of its coding pattern.

I have created a cart price rule which works fine. However now I want to show the sale watermark image on product listing page making product on sale more prominent for customers. This sale watermark must not be displayed when sale period is over.

My approach is as below

1. Modify the cart price rule form to let admin to upload corresponding sale water mark. Then update list.php to determine the rule and then add sale water mark image to product list.As cart price rule specify the sale dates, I am assuming after due date rule would become inactive and image would not get displayed.

However before i start coding for it, I am wondering if someone has easier approach.

Answer (score 0):

This extention will probably save you alot of time.

I have bought from them many times and they are great.

[AheadWorks On sale Extention (affiliate link)](http://ecommerce.go2cloud.org/aff_c?offer_id=1&aff_id=1200&source=stackoverflow&url=http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/on-sale.html)

Answer (score 0):

if products are on sale it means you are using special price??

if yes than you can use special price and follow these simple method to achieve what you want

http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-display-sale-icon-if-special-price/